# NSURLConnection threading problem

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsthread

i have a big problem and i need your help. Here's what i need to accomplish:

1. The user select a row from a
   TableView
2. A new view controller is pushed in
   the NavigationController, and
   displays only a "Loading" message
3. Meanwhile some data is read from an
   XML file (via http)
4. When the data has been read, an
   NSUConnection is used to load an
   image from an URL (this URL is part
   of the data)
5. While the image is still loading,
   the other data is displayed on the
   screen
6. The image has been downloaded and is
   shown, completing the appearance of
   the view

The big problem is that i can't use `detachNewThreadSelector` and `NSURLConnection` together!

So how can i make a workaround for this? How would you do this?

Thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a **NSTimer** to solve the problem using detachNewThreadSelector and NSURLConnection together.

---

I have similar scenario where there is a downloading Progress UIViewController showing till the file getting complete, here is what i do:

- I Draw a loading View contains a Activity Indicator for example.
- I initialize a NSTimer to keep checking if the file is complete.
- I call the method that contains the Download Logic.

**[1]**

```
 -(void) vManageFileRequest
{       
  [self.oFilesManager vGetSingleFileRequest];

   NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self   selector:@selector(vValidateFileRequest) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]];
}
```

**[2]**

```
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(vManageFileRequest) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: Please could you be a little more explicit? I don't need the code, i just want to understand your idea!

Comment: I understand your answer, but if i start the NSURLConnection inside a method called by the NSTimer that connection doesn't work. It is the same as starting it from  separated thread

Comment: No start the NSURLConnection before initializing the NSTimer the NSTimer is only for checking if the process is complete.

Comment: But I can't start the NSURLConnection on the main thread, because the URL i wan to connect to is stored in the XML, and i can't parse the XML on the main thread!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach...(if you are using asynchronous request)

When your application comes in  `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` ... add a NSInvocationOperation object in NSOperationQueue (which you can handle at application level, by synthesizing it in appDelegate) ..

create `NSInvocationOperation` as follows..(in `connectionDidFinishLoading`)

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(parseIt) object:nil];

[appDelegate.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];




-(void) parseIt
{
   //ask for parsing stuff....what you have earlier wrote directly in connectionDidFinishLoading
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Ravin, thanks for your response. My problem is that the "connectionDidFinishLoading" method is not called! I mean, it is not called if i start the connection inside a detached thread

Comment: Hi, in above suggestion,I am also using threading(with abstraction layer) as for asynchronous request main thread would not get blocked. so rather than starting connection in detached thread, I start it in main thread and then after it works .

Comment: But i can't start the NSURLConnection inside the main thread, 'cause i need to start it after the XML has been parsed. How can i start the NSURLConnection in the main thread after without executing also the XML parsing in the main thread? Maybe it is not clear, but the URL of the NSURLConnection is contained in the XML!